# How to have italic words inside regular text Scrollview?

Tags: fonts, scrollview, italics

I want to have certain words italicized within my ScrollView element. But I can't seem to figure it out, is there some code similar to like breaks (\n) that I should be putting in? I've searched google and this site but I can't quite find the right answer. I don't want the whole of the text italic, just specific words. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1.just add an UITextView to your UIScrollView in your UIView.
2.select your textview and select the Attributes Inspector and follow the remainings steps like shown in below diagram.

[image]

Follow these,it will help you.

Comment: My question relates to Android but this seems more like an xCode step - or at least I can't follow it in Android?